# how can I prove that the real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that the real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is diffeomorphic to the Lie group $SO(3)$. But I don't know how to demonstrate that this diffeomorphism preserves the structure of Lie group.

Comment: This question is only meaningful if you already have a Lie group operation defined on $\Bbb R P^3$ in the first place, and typically if you write down such an operation you're doing so in terms of a representation of $SO(3)$. Once we have such an operation, one needs to specify what the diffeomorphism $\Bbb R P^3 \to SO(3)$ *is* before one can ask whether it is a Lie group isomorphism.

Comment: One the other hand, if the question is, how can I *construct* a Lie group operation $\ast$ of $\Bbb R^3$, then you can do so by conjugating the operation $\cdot$ on $SO(3)$ by a diffeomorphism $\Phi : \Bbb R P^3 \to SO(3)$, i.e., declaring $\ell \ast \ell' := \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(\ell) \cdot \Phi(\ell'))$. It's then a matter of unwinding definitions to show that $\ast$ defines a Lie group structure.

Comment: @TravisWillse would like to thanks your answer! I agree with your answer.

Comment: Does my second comment answer your question then? If so I can write up a proper answer below for the sake of resolving this question.

Comment: Yes, this is my question

Answer (score 1):

The sphere $S^3$ is a Lie group (its group structure is given by quaternion multipication).  $\mathbb RP^3$ is obtained as the quotient Lie group $S^3/\{1,-1\}$.

The map
$$\phi : S^3 \to SU(2), \phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 +i x_2 & x_3+ix_4\\-x_3+ix_4 & x_1-ix_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
is known to be an isomorphism of Lie groups. But $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to the quotient Lie group $SU(2)/\{I,-I\}$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. See [how to show $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2\cong SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185472) .

Obviously $\phi(\{1,-1\})  = \{I,-I\}$, thus $\phi$ induces an isomorphism of Lie groups
$$\mathbb RP^3 \to SO(3) .$$

See also [Can anyone explain how the complex matrix representation of a quaternions is constructed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2148802)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned briefly in the comments, answering the question in the title (showing that $\Bbb R P^3$ admits a Lie group structure) requires only what OP already knows: That $\Bbb R P^3$ and $SO(3)$ are diffeomorphic.

Given any diffeomorphism $$\Phi : \Bbb R P^3 \to SO(3) ,$$
we can "pull back" the group operation $\cdot$ on $SO(3)$ to a group operation $\ast$ on $\Bbb R P^3$ making $\Phi$ a Lie group isomorphism, that is, define
$$\ell \ast \ell' := \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(\ell) \cdot \Phi(\ell')) .$$
With this definition, it's mostly a matter of unwinding definitions to verify that $\ast$ in fact defines a Lie group structure on $\Bbb R P^3$, that is, that the multiplication and inverse maps are smooth.

That said, constructing an explicit isomorphism $\Phi$ (and using it to write down an explicit formula for an operation $\ast$) could be an instructive exercise.

(NB this construction is very general: Given any bijection $X \to Y$ we can pull back any operation on $Y$ to an operation on $X$ making the bijection an isomorphism of sets endowed with operations.)