# Basis of the matrix representation of a quaternion

Tags: matrices, group-theory, rotations, quaternions, symmetry

I'm trying to learn some group theory for physics as a self-learner. I'm reading about rotation in 2D and 3D space. The book I'm following, Physics from symmetry by Schwichtenberg, firstly proves that the $SO(2)$ group is isomorphic to the $U(1)$, then talks about quaternions and tries to find a relation between $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$, which is the group formed by unitary quaternions.
In the first case, to do so, the author expresses complex numbers as matrices. This is clear as there can be made a map:

$$ e^{i \theta} \to \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\  
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix} = \cos \theta \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} + i\sin \theta \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

Thus $1$ and $i$ can be mapped to

$$ 1 \to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ i \to \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

The process, instead, isn't clear in the case of quaternion, for which have been chosen the following matrices:

$$ 1 \to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ i \to \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ j \to \begin{bmatrix}
0 & i \\ 
i & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ k \to \begin{bmatrix}
i & 0 \\ 
0 & -i
\end{bmatrix} $$

It is clear that this serves the purpose, but why have these matrices been chosen, is the choice purely random, or is there a motivation as for the case of 2D rotation?

P.S.: Thanks in advance for your eventual answers, and excuse my English, as I'm still learning it!

Comment: The choice is certainly not purely random. Quaternions have the property that they anti-commute and $ij=k$ holds. That's exactly what these matrices do who are closely related to the Pauli matrices. There is a lot of other literature about this including Wikipedia articles.

Comment: The quaternions are a ("right") 2-dimensional complex vector space (you apply complex scalars on the right). For any quaternion $q$, there is a left-multiplication map $L_q(x)=qx$ which is linear. Thus, if you pick the basis $\{1,{\bf j}\}$, each $L_q$ can be represented as a $2\times2$ complex matrix. That is where your representation comes from.

Comment: [This Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148802/can-anyone-explain-how-the-complex-matrix-representation-of-a-quaternions-is-con) should help.